# Regex to eliminate sub matches

Tags: regex

I need a way to exactly match the whole string in Regex and not a substring.

```
For instance,
If I look for 2 zeros only string then,

000 // not match
0 // nt match
00 // match
100 // not match
001 // not match
00300 // not match
000000 // not match
```

In simple words, if I an matching for 00 then the matched string should have only 00 as the entire string and not *containing* the 00 string any where. This I am trying to achieve in regex.

Currently I am using:

```
00{1}?
```

But it matches even if 00 is contained inside another string.

Comment: Use **word boundary**. `\b00\b`. You don't need regex, compare it using comparison operator `==`. `str == '00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "entire string" you mean "00" somewhere in the string not concatenated with any other non-whitespace characters, try this (positive lookahead and lookbehind):

```
(?<=\s|^)00(?=\s|$)
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/oJ7cM9/6

Comment: @user3243499 This should work. Did you see the demo? If it is not working add complete code with live demo if possible.

Comment: But I want it to not match for it since "00" is not same as "00.0123"

Comment: @n-dru Yes, that should work. But it really depends on the language/tool OP is using. Ex. JS don't support positive lookbehinds.

Comment: @Tushar I know, I wouldn't propose it if I saw javascript tag by the question.

Comment: @n-dru: this works only for internal lines and it has redundant ``\b``, if there is no newline before or after the ``00`` it does not match (as in the first or last line) see [here](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7cM9/5)

Comment: @n-dru : what if I want to limit the number of found matches to exactly one (to be the matching criteria) ?

Comment: @user3243499 just remove /gm flags from regex 101, it is not used in my example above, in the demo I just wanted to show different lines

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use start/end anchors around your pattern:

```
^00$
```

This will only match `00` as a valid input in a line.

However if there can be several matched in a line then you can use word boundaries: `\b00\b`

Comment: I was right about word boundary. @user3243499 use `\b00\b`, you might want to escape backslashes depending on the language/tool you're using

Comment: @user3243499: `\b00\b` will indeed give you a match for `00.0123`

Comment: But I want it to not match for it since "00" is not same as "00.0123"

Comment: Well in that case use anchors `^00$` and it won't match `00.0123`

Comment: [It works pretty well](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7cM9/3) You have comments added in each line which will fail the anchored match.